# postgres jsonb_set multiple keys update

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have DB table with jsonb column.

```
number  | data
    1   | {"name": "firstName", "city": "toronto", "province": "ON"}
```

I need a way to update data column.
So my output should look like:

```
{"name": "firstName", "city": "ottawa", "province": "ON", "phone": "phonenum", "prefix": "prefixedName"}
```

Is it possible with json_set?
I have added query like:

```
update table_name set data = jsonb_set(data, '{city}', '"ottawa"') where number = 1;
```

However, I need a way to add new key-value if it does not exists and update key value if it exists. Is it possible to achieve this in single query?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

The [documentation says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

> The || operator concatenates the elements at the top level of each of its operands. ... **For example, if both operands are objects with a common key field name, the value of the field in the result will just be the value from the right hand operand**.

So using your example data:

```
update table_name set
    data = data || '{"city": "ottawa", "phone": "phonenum", "prefix": "prefixedName"}'
    where number = 1;
```

Additionally if the object you want to edit is not at the top level - just combine the concatenation and `jsonb_set` function. For example, if the original data looks like

```
{"location": {"name": "firstName", "city": "toronto", "province": "ON"}}
```

then

```
...
data = jsonb_set(
    data, 
    '{location}', data->'location' || '{"city": "ottawa", "phone": "phonenum", "prefix": "prefixedName"}')
...
```

Comment: Awesome, this works like charm. Thanks! I am not able to up-vote it just yet because I dont have enough points, but definitely thumbs up.

Comment: @MarcoPrins Have you tried to read the Oracle documentation? Compared to it the PostgreSQL documentation is a literary masterpiece :o)

Comment: sometimes when you get the  error : unknown signature: jsonb_set(jsonb, string, jsonb) it is due to typecasting.
Adding ::TEXT[]  as shown below solved the  issue in my case
...
data = jsonb_set(data, '{location}' ::TEXT[] , data->'location' || '{"city": "ottawa", "phone": "phonenum", "prefix": "prefixedName"}' ::jsonb)
...

Comment: Helpful hint if you are populating the updated fields from dynamic data within your query, and/or updating multiple fields..  You can use `json_build_object` to create the update object.  For example: `data->'location' || jsonb_build_object('city', "cityColName", 'phonenum', "phoneCalName")`.  This is much easier than trying to dynamically creating jsonb strings as @Paarth suggests below.

Comment: I am not able use JPA Query to update multiple jsonb column fields, any help ?

Comment: I am getting ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying -> unknown
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Here we are using `jsonb` concatation operator `||` to Concatenate two jsonb objects

```
update table_name set data = (select val from (
(select 
CASE WHEN data ? key THEN jsonb_set(data, '{' || key || '}', quote_nullable(updated_value))
ELSE 
data || ('{' || quote_ident(key) || ':' || quote_ident(some_value) || '}')::jsonb
END val
 from json_each_text((select data::json from tbl))
CROSS JOIN tbl t
where key in ('city','phone','prefix') and number=1)) where number=1
```

Comment: please refer [jsonb in postgres] (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html)