# Update multiple values in a jsonb data in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I need to update a jsonb data(column->users) in my table 'settings'
 My jsonb data is like

```
'{
    "Email": "aaaa",
    "UserId": "49",
    "Created": "11/13/2016",
    "EntityId": "1",
    "IsActive": "False",
    "Modified": "11/13/2016",
    "Username": "aa"
}'
```

In this json string I need to update Email,IsActive,Username together. 
I tried the below update query,its working fine. But that is for a single value updation.

```
UPDATE settings 
SET users = jsonb_set(users, '{Email}', '"aa"') 
WHERE users @> '{"UserId":"49"}';
```

How to update for multiple value updation? I am using postgres 9.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgres jsonb\_set multiple keys update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883233/postgres-jsonb-set-multiple-keys-update)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [the concatenation operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
UPDATE settings 
SET users = users || '{"Email": "new email", "IsActive": "True", "Username": "new username"}'
WHERE users @> '{"UserId":"49"}';
```