# Update jsonb column

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to update user facts inside of a column in a Postrgres db in the form designated here.

jsonb currently in data column and waiting to be updated:

`data = { "type1" : ["value1", "value2"], "type2" : ["value3"], "type3" : ["value4"] }`

jsonb that is sent up to db:

`new_jsonb = { "type1" : ["value7", "value8"], "type3" : ["value6"]}`

how the jsonb should look after it updates:

`updated_jsonb = { "type1: ["value7", "value8"], "type2": ["value3"], "type3": ["value6"] }`

The basic rules when comparing the value originally in the dataset, with the one we want to update it with are:

1. if the `new_jsonb` that's being passed up contains keys that aren't in the current `data` jsonb, then those keys get added with their values.
2. if the `new_jsonb` that's being passed up contains keys that are in the current `data` jsonb, then those keys all just replace the old keys.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883233/postgres-jsonb-set-multiple-keys-update) post did a useful job outlining the general use for the jsonb_set function, but I'm having trouble going through and making the comparison within the arrays. Specifically specifying the `path` parameter.

So basically where I'm stuck is not knowing what path to specify for this to happen. What I have is `UPDATE table_name SET data = jsonb_set(data {don't know what path should be}, new) WHERE customer_id = $customerId`. The `new_jsonb` that's passed up, won't always pass up the key-value pairs in the same order.

Comment: [PostgreSQL anti-patterns: Unnecessary json/hstore dynamic columns](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/)

Comment: Abelisto's link now broken. Link text is intriguing. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the concatenate operator:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET data = data || $newData
WHERE customer_id = $customerId;
```

Example:

```
SELECT 
    '{ "type1": ["value1", "value2"], "type2": ["value3"], "type3": ["value4"] }'::jsonb ||
    '{ "type1": ["value7", "value8"], "type3": ["value6"]}'::jsonb as result

                                  result                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"type1": ["value7", "value8"], "type2": ["value3"], "type3": ["value6"]}
(1 row)
```