# How to update multiple json fields at root level with Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to update the fields `age` and `city` of one json feed using:

```
select jsonb_set(d,'{0,age,city}',d || '{"age":30,"city":"los angeles"}') 
from (
  values ('{"name":"john", "age":26,"city":"new york city"}'::jsonb)
) t(d);
```

but what I get back is:

```
{"age": 26, "city": "new york city", "name": "john"}
```

instead of the expected:

```
{"age": 30, "city": "los angeles", "name": "john"}
```

that means none of the wanted fields have been updated.

I have already looked at:

[postgres jsonb_set multiple keys update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883233/postgres-jsonb-set-multiple-keys-update)

and went through the relative documentation but I cannot get it right. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

> All the items of the `path` parameter of `jsonb_set` as well as `jsonb_insert` except the last item must be present in the target.

The path given in the query does not meet the above condition. Actually, `jsonb_set()` does not work for objects at the root level, and the only way is to use the `||` operator:

```
select d || '{"age":30,"city":"los angeles"}'
from (
    values ('{"name":"john", "age":26,"city":"new york city"}'::jsonb)
) t(d);

                      ?column?                      
----------------------------------------------------
 {"age": 30, "city": "los angeles", "name": "john"}
(1 row)
```

Maybe it would be logical that you could use an empty path

```
select jsonb_set(d, '{}', d || '{"age":30,"city":"los angeles"}')
```

Unfortunately, jsonb developers did not provide such a possibility.